# How to deploy Mathematica applications?

Tags: mathematica

How does one deploy Mathematica applications?  It seems that the only option is to use the Mathematica player (http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/interactivedeployment/compare.html).  Is this correct?

There is no way to compile Mathematica code into an .exe?  I know about MathCode (http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mathcode/) but it does not seem to compile the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options, all described here: [Document and Deploy](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/overview/deploy.html)

To summarize:

- Through **Mathematica Player** (which you
  could see as another type of Flash
  Player and is thus an executable
  meant to view Mathematica
  notebooks).
- Through a **Language API** (which allows
  you to embed Mathematica in your
  language of choice, provided there's
  an API for it. For instance, J/Link
  or .Net/link for Java and C#
  respectively. You can either use the programming language inside Mathematica, or create applications in the programming language that use Mathematica Kernel and objects.)
- Through **webMathematica** (which allows
  you to deploy to webservers and make
  your work accessible through a
  browser equipped with the necessary
  plugin)

There's a couple more options. But these are the ones more approximate to your requirements.